# In gnome, how to get focus but not take window to top?

Tags: gnome, archlinux

I use Archlinux. After latest update, my gnome 3 gets a property that a window can get focus without overlap other windows. I like it. But when I copy my configuration to another Archlinux (same version), it doesn't behave like that.

So, how to configure gnome to keep that property?

Comment: I have resolved this problem. In dconf-editor, set raise-on-click to false is OK. Thank to everybody!